# How to serialize a value class with moshi so it just return it's value

Tags: kotlin, serialization, moshi, value-class

I hava a `value class`in my android project (kotlin) and I want to parse a object, that contains this value class as type for a attribute, to json.

Let's say this is my `value class`:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
@JvmInline
value class CustomDate(val value: String)
```

and this is my object that contains a attribute with the value class shown before:

```
data class MyTestClass(
    val attr1: CustomDate
)
```

If I now try to convert it to Json using moshi I will get this:

```
...
attr1: {
   value: "a test valu"
}
...
```

What I want it to transform the object to this:

```
...
attr1: "a test valu"
...
```

but I don't know how to achieve this. There is no `JsonTransformingSerializer` for moshi like it seems so how am I able to transform the object itself and not only the value like done using a `JsonAdapter`?

Maybe I missed something but I would appriciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found how how to use it in case anyone is facing the same problem:

I needed to create a custom `JsonAdapter.Factory` and a according  `JsonAdapter<CustomDate>`:

```
class CustomDateAdapterFactory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
  override fun create(type: Type, annotations: Set<Annotation>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
    if (!annotations.isEmpty()) return null
    if (type === CustomDate::class.java) return CustomDateAdapter()
    return null
  }
}

class CustomDateAdapter : JsonAdapter<CustomDate>() {
  @FromJson
  override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): CustomDate {
    return CustomDate(reader.nextString())
  }

  @ToJson
  override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: CustomDate?) {
    writer.value(value?.value)
  }
}
```

After that I had to add the `CustomDateAdapterFactory` to my moshi builder:

```
Moshi.Builder()
  .addLast(CustomDateAdapterFactory())
  .build()
```

That's it! :)

Comment: You can more concisely use `.add(CustomDate::class.java, CustomDateAdapter())` instead of creating a factory.